# Counting cells that have data in given month

Tags: excel

I have a database that collects employee training dates and offer dates and I want to see how many employees have been trained in a given month.

My below formula checks B2's date and then counts offers in that month that have completed training, but I must be going wrong as it appears to be multiplying the figure.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(Database[Training Date],"*"))*(MONTH(Database[Offered Date])=MONTH(B2))*(YEAR(Database[Offered Date])=YEAR(B2)))
```

All I want it to do is count if the employee has a training date and ignore the blank cells in a given month.

Database Table:

```
************************************************
* Employee      * Training Date * Offered Date *
************************************************
*    John       *      YES      *  21/02/2016  *
*    Joe        *      YES      *  18/02/2016  *
*    Suzy       *               *  16/02/2016  *
************************************************
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have xl2007 or newer, try the [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED).

```
=COUNTIFS(database[training date], "yes", database[offered date], ">"&EOMONTH(B2, -1), database[offered date], "<="&EOMONTH(B2, 0))
```

The COUNIFS function is vastly superior to the the older [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-57a7bfa7-f74d-4ead-8c93-57f759c8f616) in terms of calculation load; typically 25-35%.

Your own formula could have discarded the [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) and just replied on the SUMPRODUCT.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((database[training date]="yes")*(MONTH(database[offered date])=MONTH(B2))*(YEAR(database[offered date])=YEAR(B2)))
```

Comment: Amazing thank you, I didnt know about COUNTIFS. It may take me some time to convert all my SUMPRODUCT formulas